# Too many open files while getting configuration resource

Tags: java

I have SOAP web service which is deployed on `tomcat 8.5` server and using JAVA 8.
On the server I have a configuration file which is read by my application every time that it is changed.

Here is my code

```
URL url = ConfigurationManager.class.getResource(CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
long lastModified = conn.getLastModified();
if (lastModified > instance.lastModified) {
    instance = new ConfigurationManager(conn);
}
```

When I have many requests in short time period it is throwing `Too many open files` Exception and it is throwing when I trying to get files resource

from here

```
URL url = ConfigurationManager.class.getResource(CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION);
```

I modified my code and I am reading configuration file every 2 hour, don't check anymore if file has been changed.
This solution works good but I want to read file when it is changed, not every 2 hour. Is there any solution how can I do this without `Too many open files` ?

Comment: Chances are, you do not properly close files you have opened (may be even other files than the config file).

Comment: You are leaking FDs. You need to close or disconnect this connection.

Comment: This URLConnection  object does not have any close or disconnect method

Comment: Cast the URLConnection down to something that can be disconnected?

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` has a `disconnect()` method, and its input stream has a `close()` method.